# The single word for "without any constraints"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the single word for "without any constraints"?
Or the words in the similar context.

For example,

> They express their thoughts _________.

Comment: what about unconstrained

Comment: In a positive sense?

Comment: depends on the context, can be positive

Comment: Like express their thoughts without any constraints

Comment: there, use *candidly*, *frankly* etc

Comment: without inhibition

Comment: unreservedly...

Answer (score 1):

> They express their thoughts...

There are many answers:

Openly,
Freely,
Overtly
...

Cambridge dictionary defines them as:

**openly**:

> without hiding any of your thoughts or feelings

**freely**

> without being controlled or limited

**overtly**

> done or shown publicly or in an obvious way and not secret

Answer (score 0):

I have seen ***unrestrained*** used in such contexts. It means the same as *unconstrained*.

> They express their thoughts ***unrestrained***.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[unrestrained](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unrestrained)**
>   *adjective* ​ not limited or controlled:
>
> unrestrained joy/anger/criticism